# Java can't open file with relative path

Tags: java, io, path

I'm trying to change dock icon for jar file, but it works only with absolute path:

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("/User/Project/src/main/resources/icon.png");
```

even if files are in the same package this doesn't work:

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("./icon.png");
```

Project Structure:
[image]

Comment: Where is your file? Same folder as the jar? In that case, just use "icon.png"

Comment: `../icon.png` ?

Comment: i've tested it in the same package, non of relative path variants work.
Though files from `Project/src/main/resources` are accessed from `Project/src/main/java/application` with `/fileName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("icon.png");
```

It will search the file name `icon.png` inside `main/resources`.

UPDATE:

If still not working, this should do the trick:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/main/resources/icon.png");
```

Comment: I did, in this case  icon changes to default exec logo

Comment: What do you mean by `exec logo`? Don't you have `icon.png` inside `src/main/resources`?

Comment: Yes, my `icon.png` is inside `src/main/resources`, but file is opened only if absolute path is used.

Comment: And where is `exec logo` placed in your directory structure? You said with the code that I posted, `exec logo` is loaded instead.

Comment: I meant `exec logo` provided by os

Comment: Can you post a print screen with your full directory structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142195/discussion-between-auserhimself-and-arashigor).